# Почему в результате запроса нет записей?

Tags: sql, запрос, таблицы

Есть таблица SESSIA с ФИО студента и дисциплиной.
Нужно вывести имена студентов, которые сдавали и Базы данных и Программную инженерию

Почему данный запрос ничего не выводит? Ведь мы ищем общее

```
SELECT bd.name
FROM (SELECT name
      FROM sessia
      WHERE discipline = 'База данных') bd
JOIN (SELECT name
     FROM sessia
     WHERE discipline = 'Программная инженерия') pi
ON bd.name = pi.name
```

Comment: у вас тут в запросе одни таблицы, а на скрине другие. Приведите уж тогда структуру бд нормально

Comment: SELECT * FROM \`sessia\` WHERE discipline = 'База данных' OR discipline = 'Программная инженерия';

Comment: В запросе одна таблица - сессия, просто переименовала ее))

Comment: Это что за СУБД-то?

Comment: PostgreSQL
программа pgAdmin

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sessia WHERE discipline IN ('База данных', 'Программная инженерия') GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1;`

Comment: *Почему данный запрос ничего не выводит?* Основных вариантов два. Первый - в таблице действительно нет таких данных. Второй - проблемы с charset и collation. Ну и плюс экзотика - типа не к той схеме подключился. К запросу претензий нет: https://dbfiddle.uk/ExdTftx4 Если не считать его неоптимальности, конечно.

Answer (score -2):

`SELECT name FROM sessia WHERE discipline = 'База данных' or discipline  'Программная инженерия'`

Comment: Извините, я неверно написала цель запроса. Нужно найти тех, кто сдавал И базы данных И программную инж

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]